# Minimize number of intervals for same id (Sybase IQ)

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I've been breaking my head over following problem. I have a table with an identifier, a characteristic and start and end date. Normally, at the end of an interval the characteristic should change. However, due to a glitch in the system, sequential intervals are created with the same characteristic. Example :

```
    ID  Characteristic  Start Date  End Date
    1   a               2012/06/25   2012/12/11
    1   a               2012/12/11   2013/06/24
    1   b               2013/06/24   2013/11/27
    1   a               2013/11/27   2013/12/10
    1   a               2013/12/10   2014/01/21
    1   a               2014/01/21   2014/06/15
    1   c               2014/06/15   2014/09/10
    1   c               2014/09/11   2999/12/31
```

I would like to see the max(end date) per group of id&characteristics. But the group should only remain a group within sequential timeframes. Something like:

```
ID  Characteristic  Start Date  End Date
1   a               2012/06/25  2013/06/24
1   b               2013/06/24  2013/11/27
1   a               2013/11/27  2014/06/15
1   c               2014/06/15  2999/12/31
```

I've been messing around with [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx), [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: So you're using SQL-Server 2012?

Comment: Sybase IQ -- Thanks for the layout

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  What's the logic behind your expected results?

Comment: @stedes:whoops, then my links to MSDN are wrong

Comment: I would like to see the max(end date) until a new characteristic is presented

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it, but it works for the sample of data you've given above. I inserted the values into a table called #tmp so you would need to replace that with your table name. Also replace the StartDate and EndDate column names as necessary.

```
SELECT ID, Characteristic, MinStartDate, MaxEndDate
  FROM ( 
    SELECT
        ID,
        Characteristic,
        ISNULL(
            (SELECT MAX(B.EndDate) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS 'Row', * FROM #tmp) AS B WHERE B.Characteristic <> A.Characteristic AND B.Row < A.Row)
        ,
            (SELECT MIN(B.StartDate) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS 'Row', * FROM #tmp) AS B WHERE B.Characteristic = A.Characteristic AND B.Row <= A.Row)
        ) AS 'MinStartDate',
        ISNULL(
            (SELECT MIN(B.StartDate) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS 'Row', * FROM #tmp) AS B WHERE B.Characteristic <> A.Characteristic AND B.Row > A.Row)
        ,
            (SELECT MAX(B.EndDate) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS 'Row', * FROM #tmp) AS B WHERE B.Characteristic = A.Characteristic AND B.Row >= A.Row)
        ) AS 'MaxEndDate'
    FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS 'Row', * FROM #tmp) as A
    ) AS Sub
GROUP BY ID, Characteristic, MinStartDate, MaxEndDate
ORDER BY MinStartDate
```

Comment: This is not working. I get an error : "Invalid use of an aggregate function"

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this for SQL-Server before the article had been updated to Sybase. Try my slight modification above and if it doesn't work I'll take the answer down.

Comment: Not working, same error. But thanks anyway. I'll also adapt the example so that it covers my case better.

Comment: Ok, sorry this didn't work. I'll leave it up here to help in case you need to refer to it for ideas. If all else fails perhaps you might want to write a script in code to run through the entries and get what you need to update your original data source. Let me know if you want me to remove my answer. If/when you figure it out, please self-answer your question for others to see.